# Open PDF in new Tab ( Javascript ) when getting data through curl

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf, curl

I have a question. I have a url for Phantomjs which generates a PDF. But I want to generate the PDF on Serverside.

```
<script> $("#generatePDF").click(function(){
        var fullLink = "<? echo $link ?>"
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/php/ajax/generatepdf.php?",
            data: {link : fullLink}
        }).done( function(data){
            window.open(data);
        } );
    }); </script>
```

This is where I send the data to the generatepdf.php

The link generates a PDF with Phantom.JS

Now I do the following in the generatepdf.php

```
 $link = $_POST['link'];
 CurlConnect = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
 curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POST,   1);
 curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0 );
 $Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);
 echo $Result;
```

My question: How can I open a PDF in a new tab with the stuff from the phantom.js result?

I hope you understand my question.

Best Regards.

Comment: What library or tool are you using in `generatepdf.php` to generate PDF ???

Comment: $link contains a url which generates a PDF

Comment: Do you **have to** make a POST request to get the pdf?

Comment: You mean in the javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i got another solution. I just linked to the php page and the PHP page got the PDF content. Plus I had to change the header to application pdf

Answer (score 0):

Instead using CURL and all that stuff simply hit the `$link` of php file in new tab.. (If the file is actually generating PDF)

`window.open('Link which generates the PDF');`

Comment: Yeah thats what I was doing before but I want to generate the PDF on serverside. So I give the link to php and there it should be generated and given back to javascript

Comment: It depends on the logic. What are you using in php for PDF? are you using TCPDF or MPDF like libraries?

Comment: Its just a URL to phantom.js

Comment: Then I guess you need to store generated PDF somewhere on the server and same hit the `path' of the stored PDF, :P